# Arena Software and Mac OS X

Tags: software

Does someone know or have tested a way of using ARENA software on Mac OS X?

Maybe using Wine or something similar.

Comment: A version for Mac has been released and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Chessfiles [ref. 1], Arena [ref. 2] can be played on OS X within Wine 1.0 or higher [ref. 3]. Likewise, Arena claims to function within Wine 1.0 or higher.

Caveat: some indicate Arena to be unstable within Wine [ref. 4], some have no problem [ref. 5, 6].

---

**References:**

1. http://www.chessfiles.com/os-x-chess-gui.html
2. http://www.playwitharena.com/
3. https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX
4. http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6550
5. http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-377613.html
6. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=31659